# OSX Bitcoin Core frozen on login while "Activating Best Chain"

Tags: wallet, private-key-export

I recently downloaded Bitcoin Core for OSX, sent a payment to my wallet address, then waited for the client to complete a sync. About 2 days later and w/ only 8 weeks to go, the client froze. Upon restart, it only gets to "Activating Best Chain" and won't open fully.

I've seen related answers to this question in the forum, but I think they're all for Windows machines.

I do have my wallet encrypted.

I'd like to export my wallet to another client, but apparently am not using the correct inputs in console. Any help much appreciated.

cheers

...and when I try to run:
getwalletpassword "pwd" 600 
the application crashes and I have to restart. So it doesn't look like the standard way to get my privkey out will work.

Comment: Have you looked at the debug.log file?

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed the same problem by deleting a circular symlink:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 2can  staff       17 Mar  7  2015 bootstrap.dat.old -> bootstrap.dat.old
```

in my `data` folder. The `db.log` file contained only one repeating error:

```
Too many levels of symbolic links
```